# How can I limit the number of times a message is displayed while in a for loop in java?

Tags: java, java-8

> The maximum number of rows that can be displayed for for loop statements is 11, regardless of reaching or exceeding the maximum value for the table.

```
for (double i = initialvalue; i <= finalvalue; i = i + increase) { 
        System.out.println(tablevalue + "*" + i + "=" + tablevalue * i);
       
    }
```

> I tried to limit it changing 'finalvalue' to 11 but that doesn't work and I get stuck, someone may can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop looks fine. Please double check if i gets increased in each loop.

If you just want to reduce the number of outputs but still iterate the full length just use a variable to check for the number of outputs:

```
int maxOutputs = 11;
for (double i = initialvalue; i <= finalvalue; i = i + increase) { 
        if(maxOutputs > 0){
           System.out.println(tablevalue + "*" + i + "=" + tablevalue * i);
           maxOutputs--;
        }  
}
```

Comment: You can move the variable into the loop head as well instead of having the increment/decrement and check in the body.